# How can I provide a Docker container with Docker credentials coming from a credentials helper?

Tags: docker

I'm making my first steps with `oras` and would like to provide some artifacts to my team. However, there are two caveats:

1. OCI artifact image is in a private registry
2. I would like to avoid requiring `oras` to be installed on every machine

So basically, I want to run `oras` in a container like this:

`docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/workspace -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker:ro ghcr.io/oras-project/oras:v1.1.0 pull $MY_OCI_IMAGE`

Under Linux with standard Docker configuration, there is no problem, since the credentials are stored under `$HOME/.docker/config.json`. However, if a credential helper is used, there are no credentials in `config.json`, so I'd need to inject them somehow.

I've got a script to extract credentials from a helper, however, this script needs to run on the host machine too and requires some tools itself (most notably `jq`). Is there a way I could somehow pass the credentials helper into the container to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom script running on the host machine.

Its purpose would be to interact with the credential helper to extract the necessary Docker credentials. Once the credentials are obtained, the script can pass them to the Docker container. This can be done through environment variables, command-line arguments, or by writing them to a file that is then mounted into the container.

And you could create a custom Dockerfile:

The Dockerfile includes [`oras`](https://oras.land/docs/commands/use_oras_cli) and any additional tools you might need (like `jq` if it's needed within the container). The image is configured to expect Docker credentials in a specific manner (e.g., reading from an environment variable or a file).
When you run a container using this image, it uses the credentials passed to it (via the script mentioned above) to authenticate with the private registry.

These two parts work together:

- The **custom script** on the host handles the complexity of interacting with the credential helper and securely passing the credentials to the Docker container.
- The **custom Docker container**, prepared through the Dockerfile, is set up to receive and use these credentials for its operations, such as pulling an OCI artifact from a private registry.

The script can be adapted to different host environments or credential helpers, and the Docker container remains focused solely on its primary task, unaffected by the credential extraction logic.

For the script, something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the registry for which you want to get credentials
REGISTRY="your.private.registry.com"

# Extract credentials using Docker credential helper
CREDENTIALS=$(echo "$REGISTRY" | docker-credential-secretservice get)

# Parse username and password
USERNAME=$(echo "$CREDENTIALS" | jq -r '.Username')
PASSWORD=$(echo "$CREDENTIALS" | jq -r '.Secret')

# Check if credentials were successfully extracted
if [ -z "$USERNAME" ] || [ -z "$PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "Failed to extract credentials."
    exit 1
fi

# Pass credentials to Docker container and run your command
# Replace `your_docker_command_here` with the actual Docker command you want to run
docker run -it --rm \
  -e DOCKER_USERNAME="$USERNAME" \
  -e DOCKER_PASSWORD="$PASSWORD" \
  your_docker_image your_docker_command_here
```